# Alternative for JComponent in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I am new to JavaFX and i have been recently googling around for a while to understand this. 
I am planning to rewrite an existing screen-manager framework in my project which is in Swing.
I am interested to understand what is the alternative to JComponent in FX ?
Is it Stage or window or Control or Parent, i am not able to conclude. Neither i am sure if there is such an alternative any.

Why do i need the alternative for JComponent ?
Well, in the screen-manager framework that i have in place, we always return the type for any individual swing component (say a panel) as JComponent. So i am eager to know the alternative in FX, if we have one.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat loosely, the equivalent to [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) is [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)

I say loosely, because they are different things and it isn't a 100% equivalence relation, but I guess you can think of them as roughly representing similar things.  Nodes represent more stuff than JComponents because they can represent shapes, media views, etc.

JComponent is:

> The base class for all Swing components except top-level containers. To use a component that inherits from JComponent, you must place the component in a containment hierarchy whose root is a top-level Swing container. Top-level Swing containers -- such as JFrame, JDialog, and JApplet -- are specialized components that provide a place for other Swing components to paint themselves.

And Node is:

> Base class for scene graph nodes. A scene graph is a set of tree data structures where every item has zero or one parent, and each item is either a "leaf" with zero sub-items or a "branch" with zero or more sub-items.

Note that a [Scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html) is contained within a [Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html) (or [Stage](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html)), so somewhat analogous to a JComponent, a window is not a Node (but pretty much everything else that JavaFX displays is).

See the Working with the [Scene Graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/scenegraph/jfxpub-scenegraph.htm) tutorial from Oracle for more information on what Nodes are and how they are used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good bunch of information. That was a neat explanation. Thanks again.