# JavaFX: How can I migrate JComponent?

Tags: swing, javafx, jcomponent

I'm migrating a swing application to JavaFX. There is a lot of Code, that abstracts from JComponent.

```
public abstract class ComponentLayoutHelper<TComponent extends Componend>{...
```

> componend.setBorder()
>
> ...}

Properties like the visibility, border and opaque is set to a Component first and afterwards the properties are extended for specific Components like Labels etc.

`public class LabelLayoutHelper extends ComponendLayoutHelper<JLabel>{...`

> label.setText();
>
> ...}

In this post:
[Alternative for JComponent in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792587/alternative-for-jcomponent-in-javafx) they talked about Node as an equivalent to JComponent. But node doesnt have properties like border or opaque. Does someone have an idea how to migrate JComponent?

Comment: [opacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#opacityProperty) is a node property.  Node also has a [visible](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#visibleProperty) property.  Anything that extends [Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) (a kind of node) can have a [Border](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/layout/Border.html).  What are your real issues?

Comment: ok the hint with opacity helped me, ty. But there are lots of other properties to set, like background forgrounf border font enabled.. which i cant set for nodes. and i want to set them in an abstract class (like they did for components)

Comment: It seems to me you're trying to program javafx like swing rather than using the new features for javafx such as fxml and css. It might just be easier to learn the new way of doing things instead of trying to put new wine in old bottles.